# Rails: Sidekiq is sometimes "down" - doesn't process requests. Is there a limit of request we can send through Sidekiq?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, sidekiq

We have added a few weeks ago monitoring user activity in our system, something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :log_request

  def log_request
    params_to_parse = params
    all_params      = params.except(:controller, :action).inspect.gsub("✓", "")
    RequestLoggerWorker.perform_async(params[:controller], 
                                      params[:action], 
                                      (current_admin.nil? ? nil : current_admin.id), 
                                      request.method, 
                                      ...)
  end
end
```

The Sidekiq method:

```
class RequestLoggerWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(...)
    ActivityLog.create(admin_id:        admin_id,
                       controller_log:  controller,
                       ...)
  end
end
```

Through this mechanism, we save like 4,000 clicks a day. This part seems to be working well.

What we have noticed, though, that since the time we implemented this Sidekiq has blackouts - this morning twice. Actions that we using Sidekiq were not processed.

I needed to log in to our Ubuntu server (AWS EC2) and manually run Sidekiq (`RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec sidekiq`).

What's causing shutting down Sidekiq? I am trying to research this, but I am not successful so far.

Our Sidekiq config (`config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`):

```
  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url:       "redis://deployer_redis@IP:6379/#{env_num}", 
                     namespace: "sidekiq_myapp_com_#{Rails.env}" }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url:       "redis://deployer_redis@IP:6379/#{env_num}", 
                     namespace: "sidekiq_myapp_com_#{Rails.env}" }
  end
```

As a temporary solution, I needed to turn off this morning the activity logging mechanism.

Every help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: What do your logs say? Also do you have something like sidekiq-web up and running?

Answer (score 3):

You aren't starting Sidekiq as a proper system service so it runs 24/7. You need to integrate Sidekiq into Ubuntu's Upstart config.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Deployment#daemonization
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/tree/master/examples/upstart